# Salesforce Graphql Schema object is missing some field/objects

Tags: schema, schema-builder, graphql

I'm currently experimenting with Salesforce GraphQL at https://.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v60.0/graphql.

I've successfully pulled the GraphQL schema from the above URL, but unfortunately, some objects/fields are missing, such as AccountPartnerUpdateRepresentation. This has led to cases where I can't generate TypeScript for our endpoint, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

I've also attempted to inject the above GraphQL URI into the Altair GraphQL tool (as the documentation suggested), but it also returns "missing", as depicted in the screenshot below:

[image]

Does it happen because my account do not enough permission or this is salesforce behavior?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you'd like to increase the chances of your question getting answered, please copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.